# Can someone explain this code for binary to unsigned int

Tags: c, pointers, int

I dont understand how the for loop has bits++ (how can we increment a char pointer?) and how does this code produce an int?

```
int16_t binary_to_int(char *bits) {

    int16_t result;

    for (result = 0; *bits; bits++) {
        if (*bits == '1') 
            result = (result << 1) | 1;
        else if (*bits == '0' ) 
            result <<= 1;
        else 
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `bits` is a `char *` and a `char` is 8-bits, `bits` would point to one address and `bits + 1` would point to another address that is the first address + 1.  For example, if `bits` is address `0x1000`, `bits + 1` is address `0x1001`.

Comment: Why can't you increment a pointer? That changes it to point to the next element.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reread the chapter on pointers from wherever you learned C.

Comment: @FiddlingBits so its basically means that we are incrementing the index of the char array?

Comment: @shellysu `*(bits + 1)` would be equivalent to `bits[1]`.

Comment: That is not code to convert binary to `unsigned int`. You can tell from the `int16_t`, which is a 16-bit signed integer, not an unsigned integer. And that means, if the high bit is set, there will be an implementation-defined conversion in `result = (result << 1) | 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

`bits` is a `char*` pointing to a string. In fact it points to the 1st character of that string, and `bits++` moves the pointer to the next character of the string. `*bits` defereferences the pointer returns the current `char` being pointed to, so it can be used in a condition to check if the 0-terminator of the string has been reached.